# Array Index Out Of Bounds Exception Java Game

Tags: java, exception, arraylist, linked-list, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm creating a game in java and I'm attempting to create a multiplayer for it, when the game first starts, the level is loaded and the client is added to a playerlist which is clientside, the client will iterate through the list and add more if the server tells it to but the problem is that I'm getting 'ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException' whent he game first starts, I've instructed my game to ignore it, I cant seem to fine the problem.

I'm assuming its something to do with creating new player and the time it takes for the threads to do their work but was hoping someone could help!

The message var is a String recieved fromt he server formatted like this:

name;address;posX;posY;fakeRotation;rotation;rotationSpeed;speed;sheildEnabled;sheildHealth;health

Here is an example of what the server sends:

```
Luke;/127.0.0.1:53701;50.0;50.0;0.0;0.0;0.0;0.0;true;100;100
```

Here are the vars:

```
String[] decrypted = message.split(",");
String[] commands = decrypted[x].split(";");
```

Here's the piece of code that's troubling me:

```
 boolean newPlayer = true;
        if(Main.level.playerList != null)
        {
            try
            {
                for(int p = 0; p < Main.level.playerList.size(); p++)
                {
                    if(Main.level.playerList.get(p).address.toString().equals(commands[1]))
                    {
                        newPlayer = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if(newPlayer)
                {
                    Player player = new Player(50, 50, 100, 150, commands[1], Main.level.shipImage1, Main.level.thrusterFlamesSprite1, Main.level.shieldSprite1);
                    Main.level.playerList.add(player);
                }

                for(int p = 0; p < Main.level.playerList.size(); p++)
                {
                    Player player = Main.level.playerList.get(p);

                    if(player.address.equals(commands[1]))
                    {
                        // name:address:posX:posY:fakeRotation:rotation:rotationSpeed:speed:sheildEnabled:sheildHealth:health
                        player.name = commands[0];
                        player.address = commands[1];
                        player.pos[0] = Double.parseDouble(commands[2]);
                        player.pos[1] = Double.parseDouble(commands[3]);
                        player.fakeRotation = Float.parseFloat(commands[4]);
                        player.rotation = Float.parseFloat(commands[5]);
                        player.rotationSpeed = Double.parseDouble(commands[6]);
                        player.speed = Double.parseDouble(commands[7]);
                        player.sheildEnabled = Boolean.parseBoolean(commands[8]);
                        player.sheildStrength = Integer.parseInt(commands[9]);
                        //player.health = Integer.parseInt(commands[10]);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e)
            {
                System.out.println("Array index out of bounds, continuing.");

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Hopefully someone can help, like I said i think its somethign to do with adding a 'new' item but I can't find any way to make it work!

The stack trace I receive is:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
at multiplayer.Translator.interperate(Translator.java:28)
at multiplayer.GameClient.run(GameClient.java:81)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How is `command[]` declared?  For what you have currently, it has to be at least 10.  If you uncomment the health line, it has to be 11.  How did you initialize `command[]`?

Comment: sorry, command is String[] commands = decrypted[x].split(";"); and decrypted is decrypted = message.split(",");

Comment: message is formatted like name;address;posX;posY;fakeRotation;rotation;rotationSpeed;speed;sheildEnabled;sheildHealth;health

Comment: Please edit that into your post above, even if there is extra code you don't want to add.  Just put a comment after it saying (snip) or something.  Ok, so according to the stack trace, are the errors happening on the `health` line?  If so, `decrypted[x]` may not have enough semicolons in it.

Comment: Can you post the stack trace please?

Comment: I added it to the original question.

Comment: @LukeAlderton ***(Translator.java:28)*** points to which line of your code posted above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the stack trace, is the error happening on the `health` line? If so, decrypted[x] may not have enough semicolons in it.

edit -

```
  String[] commands = decrypted[x].split(";");
```

So, what is `x`?
When you look at all `decrypted[x]` do you see what you expect?  Is that value the 'Luke' data you posted earlier?

edit - also, I recommend you replace the 0 and 1 in `pos[0]` and `pos[1]` with `static final` constants:

```
  private static final int X_COORD = 0;
  private static final int Y_COORD = 1;
  /* ... snip ... */
  player.pos[X_COORD] = Double.parseDouble(commands[2]);
  player.pos[Y_COORD] = Double.parseDouble(commands[3]);
```

The point of this is to allow your code to refer to the X and Y coordinates by a descriptive constant instead of a number.  While right now you know what 0 and 1 mean, a few months from now you won't, and when you look back ont he code you'll be mystified or confused. Adding the constants means you don't have to remember.  It will also help you spot errors.

Comment: Accordign to the stack trace I recieve, the error is happening when I try to compare the player address with the command address

Comment: Ok, then right after you create the `command` array, print out the number of elements in that array.  Better yet, step through it with the debugger and see what's happening.

Comment: Okay, apparently the server sends 1 command for the first time then sends 11 commands each time after that so maybe the server has a problem?

Comment: What is the purpose of the static final constants?

Comment: It's hard to tell, we can't really see your code.  Which exact line that's causing the problem?

Comment: @LukeAlderton ***(Translator.java:28)*** points to which line of your code posted above?

Comment: if(Main.level.playerList.get(p).address.toString().equals(commands[1])) is the line thats causing the problem

Comment: No, that's the symptom.  The line that's causing your problem is more likely the one loading commands[] with data.  See my post above for an edit (in a few seconds, heh.)

Comment: @LukeAlderton So, what is `x` value in comparison with `decrypted.length`?

Comment: Okay, so X is just a number incremented from 0 in a for loop, the data being output is exactly what I expect it to be, I think the server may be sending some data that the client doesn't expect when the first client joins the server... There can't be any other reason as far as I can see!

Comment: The for loop is for(int x = 0; x < decrypted.length; x++)

Comment: I just tested the `split` line and it splits fine. So this is perplexing.  If the server is sending the wrong data, you need to detect this.  Try changing your code so if `decrypt[]` doesn't have the number of elements you expect, throw a `RuntimeException`. Same for `commands[]` - if the number of commands isn't what you expect, throw an exception.  Then you'll know more and can put in debug lines to help you find out what's happening.

Comment: Well at least with your help I now know its not the clients fault, I've made the client check the length of the received data before processing it now, and the problem has gone away! I was kind of hoping that fixing this would have fixed a problem with the server having two players connect even though its only one player that's connecting but it doesn't seem to, but oh well, one problem fixed, now to move onto the next haha.

Comment: Well, the problem didn't go away - you're just hiding it, right?  Anyway, glad I could help.

Comment: Nah, the problem is still there and yes I'm hiding it but with your help I've been pointed in the right direction and will hopefully be able to fix it now, time to go check the server app I guess. Thanks anyway dude.